# Javascript ruby selenium - как вывести переменную в alert?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Как вывести значение переменной в `alert` javascript?

Вот мой код:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser= Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

browser.manage.window.resize_to(1804,1096) 

browser.navigate.to "https://www.google.com"

text = "Some text"

browser.execute_script('alert(text)')
```

Comment: Заджейсонить её в сунуть в строку со скриптом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Берёте [модуль `JSON`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-dump), и...

```
require 'json'

# ...

text = "Some text"
js_value = JSON.dump(text)

browser.execute_script("alert(#{js_value})") # < внимание, ДВОЙНЫЕ кавычки
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^^    #   существенно только тут, из-за #{ }
#                                            #   (интерполяции строк)
```

С интерполяцией строк можно познакомиться [в руководстве "Ruby за 20 минут", на второй странице](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ru/documentation/quickstart/2/). Но ознакомиться [с полным текстом](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ru/documentation/quickstart/) будет тоже полезно.

Comment: Не считаю этот ответ "простым и банальным", посколько вообще не вижу смысла в модуле JSON здесь. `alert`-то строку ждет.

Comment: @Nakilon предлагаете .inspect'ить? А уверены, что форматы выводов не различаются?

Comment: @D-side, во-первых, думаю, что разницей в кодировании строк между Ruby и JS можно по возможности пренебречь. Во-вторых, если уж с одной стороны привели к JSON, то вс другой должно быть что-то вроде `alert(JSON.parse(#{js_value}))` http://stackoverflow.com/a/5686237/322020

Comment: А лучше тогда уж Base64 и толи atob(), толи btoa().

Comment: @Nakilon пренебрегать разницей, где она может быть, опасно. Нет, после приведения к JSON не нужно вставлять ещё и `JSON.parse`, т. к. это только для руби строка, а после интерполяции в код для JS это будет голый литерал. Но [на самом деле не совсем, может выйти и синтаксическая ошибка](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset). Так что приведённое решение можно улучшить, разве что учтя несовместимости в JSON для JS. Вот.